# vc_redist.x86.exe has changed since it was initially published

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

I am publishing a clickonce application using Visual Studio 2017, setting a prerequisite for C++ 14 Runtime libraries, to download from the vendors site.
At installation this error is generated and the install does not proceed. The log file ends with this:

> Error: Setup has detected that the file
>   'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDC9DA.tmp\vcredist_x86\vc_redist.x86.exe'
>   has changed since it was initially published.